# Final render isn't showing composite background color

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, color, render-layers

I'm following Blender Guru's donut tutorial and this is my first go at 3D rendering. I have a problem I can't seem to solve. I created a background color for my donut in compositing, and I can see it on the viewer that it looks great, but when I render it, the color does not show up. The background just shows nothing (checkered background).

[image]

Comment: Not sure, but try unchecking the *Alpha* checkbox on the *Composite* node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that in *Output Properties* > *Post Processing* > *Pipeline* the option **Compositing** is enabled. If that's the case but the *Image Editor* still shows only a transparent background as *Render Result*, make sure the layer selection is set to **Composite** and not *View Layer*.

[image: composite layer]

By the way, if you have a render layer with transparent background, it's not necessary to plug the *Alpha* output into the *Fac* input of the *Alpha Over* node, it uses the transparency of the render layer naturally.

The *Fac* input can be used as a mix factor, so for example if you set it to 0.5 instead of 1, the image on top is semi-transparent where the original is opaque. Or if you have a different image or mask or whatever you want to use to control the mixing, you can plug it in there, too.

But note: whatever you plug in there is working as a mix factor, it's not replacing the original *Alpha* of the image.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks!!